# is there a way to test if an activerecord collection contains any of an array of records in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a test :

```
let!(:things_I_dont_want_to_appear) { create_list :books, archived }
expect(assign(:things).to_a).not_to include(things_I_dont_want_to_appear)
```

I used to_a because things_I_dont_want_to_appear is an array, however 'include' does not seem to be able to handle object comparisons?

Comment: `things_I_dont_want_to_appear` is Array or what kind of object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
expect(assign(:things).to_a).not_to include(*things_I_dont_want_to_appear)
```

Read [array usage](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-2/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher#array-usage). With `Array`, `#include` must need to have a list of comma(`,`) separated arguments. And **splat(`*`)** does the job for you.

Comment: Thanks. This worked, though it did look like they were comma separated values, before I used the splat,, rspec failure would show `expect(assigns(: things).to_a.map(&:id)).to include(things_I_dont_want_to_appear.map(&:id))
       expected [1, 2] to include [1, 2]`